# Hue supervisor startup error hadoop working fine - Python packages in hue not working

Tags: python, mysql, hadoop, hive, hue

I have installed hadoop, all services working well. similarly hue installed as per instruction and configured properly (similarly hive). Everything i have checked many times its good. But when i try to start hue(supervisor) i got this error. Please suggest what should i do to solve this.

```
root@xxx:/usr/local/master/hue/build/env# bin/supervisor
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('desktop==1.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 73, in entry
execute_manager(settings)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/management/commands/beeswax_server.py", line 70, in handle_noargs
is_local, host, port = beeswax.hive_site.get_metastore()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 73, in get_metastore
is_local = get_conf().getbool(_CNF_METASTORE_LOCAL, True)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 56, in get_conf
_parse_hive_site()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 110, in _parse_hive_site
_HIVE_SITE_DICT = confparse.ConfParse(data)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/confparse.py", line 44, in __init__
parser.Parse(conf)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 24, column 6
(27536) *** Controller starting at Tue Mar  4 22:32:20 2014
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('desktop==1.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 73, in entry
execute_manager(settings)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/management/commands/beeswax_server.py", line 70, in handle_noargs
is_local, host, port = beeswax.hive_site.get_metastore()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 73, in get_metastore
is_local = get_conf().getbool(_CNF_METASTORE_LOCAL, True)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 56, in get_conf
_parse_hive_site()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 110, in _parse_hive_site
_HIVE_SITE_DICT = confparse.ConfParse(data)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/confparse.py", line 44, in __init__
parser.Parse(conf)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 24, column 6
Should start 1 new children
Controller.spawn_children(number=1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('desktop==1.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 73, in entry
execute_manager(settings)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/management/commands/beeswax_server.py", line 70, in handle_noargs
is_local, host, port = beeswax.hive_site.get_metastore()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 73, in get_metastore
is_local = get_conf().getbool(_CNF_METASTORE_LOCAL, True)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 56, in get_conf
_parse_hive_site()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 110, in _parse_hive_site
_HIVE_SITE_DICT = confparse.ConfParse(data)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/confparse.py", line 44, in __init__
parser.Parse(conf)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 24, column 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/bin/hue", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('desktop==1.2.0', 'console_scripts', 'hue')()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/manage_entry.py", line 73, in entry
execute_manager(settings)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
return self.handle_noargs(**options)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/management/commands/beeswax_server.py", line 70, in handle_noargs
is_local, host, port = beeswax.hive_site.get_metastore()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 73, in get_metastore
is_local = get_conf().getbool(_CNF_METASTORE_LOCAL, True)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 56, in get_conf
_parse_hive_site()
File "/usr/local/master/hue/apps/beeswax/src/beeswax/hive_site.py", line 110, in _parse_hive_site
_HIVE_SITE_DICT = confparse.ConfParse(data)
File "/usr/local/master/hue/desktop/libs/hadoop/src/hadoop/confparse.py", line 44, in __init__
parser.Parse(conf)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 24, column 6
(27549) *** Child exiting
(27536) *** Controller exiting
```

I have installed python, mysql also. In mysql i have created a database hadoop. Everything i did as per my previous hue installation exp. Thats working fine. But this installation giving problems.

Answer (score 0):

You hive-site.xml (generally $HIVE_CONF_DIR/hive-site.xml) is not well formed, hence can't be parsed and understood by Hue.

> xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 24, column 6